# What are the solutions to $\cot(x) = \frac 1 2 \left ( x - \frac 1 x \right )$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, roots

Is there an explicit set of solutions for the equation:

$$ \cot(x) = \frac 1 2 \left ( x - \frac 1 x \right ) $$ ?

I am reading a paper in which they state that this is standard without giving solutions neither references.

Thank you all very much in advance,

Comment: $\left\{x:\cot(x)=\frac12\left(x-\frac1x\right)\right\}$. As far as solving for $x$ in closed form, that cannot be done. In general trying to solve a mix of algebraic and trigonometric functions is not doable, save for special values.

Comment: Thank you very much @SimplyBeautifulArt, would anyone know of a way to compute them numerically then ?

Comment: Use any root-finding method, such as Newton's method. Bisection happens to work well here since you know where the poles of $\cot(x)$ are, so you know the intervals over which the roots should appear.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt thank you very much, this works indeed!

Comment: For this kind of numerical problem the approach I have proposed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543020/searching-for-tighter-bounds) should work pretty well.

Comment: It is $x=\pi n+\frac i2\ln\left(1-\frac{2 i x}{(x+i)^2}\right)$ which is likely solved via [Lagrange reversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) and [this Stirling S1 series](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/StirlingS1/23/02/0001/)

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the zeros of function
$$f(x)=\cot(x) - \frac 1 2 \left ( x - \frac 1 x \right )$$ is the same as looking for the zeros of function
$$g(x)=\left(x^2-1\right) \sin (x)-2 x \cos (x)$$ which is much better conditioned.

Beside the first root, the zeros of $g(x)$ are closer and closer to $n\pi$ because of the $x^2$ term. Using series expansion and power series reversion,
$$x_ {(n)}=n\pi+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} a_k\, t^k\qquad \text{where}\qquad t=\frac{2 \pi  n}{\pi ^2 n^2-3}$$

The first coefficients are
$$\left\{1,\frac{3 \pi  n}{\pi ^2 n^2-3},\frac{\pi ^4 n^4+92 \pi ^2
   n^2+39}{6 \left(\pi ^2 n^2-3\right)^2},\frac{5 \pi  n \left(5 \pi
   ^4 n^4+234 \pi ^2 n^2+225\right)}{12 \left(\pi ^2
   n^2-3\right)^3}\right\} $$

Using only the terms given in the table, some results

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 2 & 6.5800222 &  6.5846200 \\
 3 & 9.6314973 &  9.6316846 \\
 4 & 12.723216 &  12.723241 \\
 5 & 15.834100 &  15.834105 \\
 6 & 18.954970 &  18.954971 \\
 7 & 22.081659 &  22.081660 \\
 8 & 25.212027 &  25.212027 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$